# why I am getting these errors while upgrading or installing a package?

Tags: 16.04, dpkg

```
[rajeev@MacBook-Pro ~ ]$ sudo apt upgrade    
[sudo] password for rajeev: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up brltty (5.3.1-2ubuntu2.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'S99runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1

insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv: There is a loop at service runlcactivator if started
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package brltty (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up udev (229-4ubuntu5) ...
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'S99runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv: There is a loop at service runlcactivator if started
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-drivers-common:
 ubuntu-drivers-common depends on udev (>= 204-0ubuntu4~); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-drivers-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Setting up plymouth (0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: warning: script 'S99runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1

insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv: There is a loop at service runlcactivator if started

insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package plymouth (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth-label:
 plymouth-label depends on plymouth (= 0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1); however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plymouth-label (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo:
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo depends on plymouth (= 0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1); however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo depends on plymouth-label (= 0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1); however:
  Package plymouth-label is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text:
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text depends on plymouth (= 0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1); however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up thermald (1.5-2ubuntu1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started

insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv: There is a loop at service runlcactivator if started
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package thermald (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 brltty
 udev
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 plymouth
 plymouth-label
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
 thermald
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: It is similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/796076/package-udev-is-not-configured-yet/ . Try to follow same instructions as explained the accepted answer