# Package udev is not configured yet

Tags: upgrade, kernel, udev

Today I decided to upgrade my Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS to 16.04.
Unfortunately, the upgrade process crashed on the way, no idea why.
When I reboot I am left only with a black screen, if I choose the first Ubuntu option in Grub. However, I have an "Advanced Ubuntu Options" (or similar) where there are a bunch of different options:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-28-generic
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-28-generic (upstart)
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-28-generic (recovery mode)
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-41-generic
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-41-generic (upstart)
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-41-generic (recovery mode)
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-38-generic
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-38-generic (upstart)
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-38-generic (recovery mode)
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-36-generic
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-36-generic (upstart)
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-36-generic (recovery mode)
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-35-generic
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-35-generic (upstart)
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-35-generic (recovery mode)
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-34-generic
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-34-generic (upstart)
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-34-generic (recovery mode)
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-30-generic
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-30-generic (upstart)
        Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-30-generic (recovery mode)
Memory test (memtest86+)'
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)
Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)
```

If I choose any of the first three (which have the highest version), it does not boot, I get a "Kernel Panic error....".

If I choose any subsequent linux 4.x.x option it boots to the login screen, but when I type the username and password the screen goes black for 1-2 seconds and it returns back to the login screen.

However, If I choose an "Upstart" option I can access a headless version of the system. With some config I can connect to the internet so I can try to update.
Unfortunately, when I try to upgrade I get the following:

```
mmv@mmv:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
318 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Setting up udev (229-4ubuntu6) ...
addgroup: The group `input' already exists and is not a system group. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools-core:
 initramfs-tools-core depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools:
 initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-core (= 0.122ubuntu8.1); however:
  Package initramfs-tools-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of brltty:
 brltty depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.40ubuntu30); however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package brltty (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluez:
 bluez depends on udev (>= 170-1); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error prNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                        No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                                               ocessing package bluez (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth:
 plymouth depends on initramfs-tools | dracut; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
  Package dracut is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package plymouth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mountall:
 mountall depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
 mountall depends on plymouth; however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mountall (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upstart:
 upstart depends on mountall; however:
  Package mountall is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package upstart (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apparmor:
 apparmor depends on initramfs-tools | linux-initramfs-tool; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
  Package linux-initramfs-tool is not installed.
  Package initramfs-tools which provides linux-initramfs-tool is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apparmor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lightdm:
 lightdm depends on plymouth (>= 0.8.8-0ubuntu18); however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lightdm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-5.7:
 mysql-server-5.7 depends on apparmor (>= 2.10); however:
  Package apparmor is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-drivers-common:
 ubuntu-drivers-common depends on udev (>= 204-0ubuntu4~); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-drivers-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.85eubuntu12) | linux-initramfs-tool; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
  Package linux-initramfs-tool is not installed.
  Package initramfs-tools which provides linux-initramfs-tool is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kbd:
 kbd depends on console-setup | console-setup-mini; however:
  Package console-setup is not configured yet.
  Package console-setup-mini is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package kbd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup-linux:
 console-setup-linux depends on kbd (>= 1.15-1ubuntu3); however:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

  Package kbd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text:
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text depends on plymouth (= 0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1); however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu:
 apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu depends on apparmor (>= 2.9.1-0ubuntu4~); however:
  Package apparmor is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of media-player-info:
 media-player-info depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package media-player-info (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox:
 rhythmbox depends on media-player-info; however:
  Package media-player-info is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder:
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder depends on rhythmbox (= 3.3-1ubuntu7); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist:
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist depends on rhythmbox (>= 3.3-1ubuntu7); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist depends on rhythmbox (<< 3.4); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugins:
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on rhythmbox (= 3.3-1ubuntu7); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-plugins (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udisks2:
 udisks2 depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package udisks2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs-daemons:
 gvfs-daemons depends on udisks2; however:
  Package udisks2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs-daemons (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs:amd64:
 gvfs:amd64 depends on gvfs-daemons (>= 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.1); however:
  Package gvfs-daemons is not configured yet.
 gvfs:amd64 depends on gvfs-daemons (<< 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.1.1~); however:
  Package gvfs-daemons is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nautilus:
 nautilus depends on gvfs (>= 1.3.2); however:
  Package gvfs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nautilus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of brasero:
 brasero depends on gvfs; however:
  Package gvfs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package brasero (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-apparmor-click:
 python3-apparmor-click depends on apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu (>= 1.0.17); however:
  Package apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-apparmor-click (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of click-apparmor:
 click-apparmor depends on python3-apparmor-click (= 0.3.13.1); however:
  Package python3-apparmor-click is not configured yet.
 click-apparmor depends on apparmor (>= 2.9.1-0ubuntu8~pre8); however:
  Package apparmor is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package click-apparmor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager:
 network-manager depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of indicator-network:
 indicator-network depends on network-manager; however:
  Package network-manager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package indicator-network (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upower:
 upower depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package upower (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of indicator-power:
 indicator-power depends on upower; however:
  Package upower is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package indicator-power (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of powerd:
 powerd depends on upower; however:
  Package upower is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package powerd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pulseaudio:
 pulseaudio depends on udev (>= 143); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pulseaudio (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of indicator-sound:
 indicator-sound depends on pulseaudio; however:
  Package pulseaudio is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package indicator-sound (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-bluetooth:
 gnome-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 5.5); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.
 gnome-bluetooth depends on udev (>= 154); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of indicator-bluetooth:
 indicator-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 5); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package indicator-bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-control-center:
 unity-control-center depends on indicator-bluetooth; however:
  Package indicator-bluetooth is not configured yet.
 unity-control-center depends on indicator-power; however:
  Package indicator-power is not configured yet.
 unity-control-center depends on indicator-sound; however:
  Package indicator-sound is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unity-control-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-system-settings:
 ubuntu-system-settings depends on bluez (>= 5.23); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-system-settings depends on indicator-bluetooth (>> 0.0.6+13.10.20131010); however:
  Package indicator-bluetooth is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-system-settings depends on indicator-network (>= 0.7.1); however:
  Package indicator-network is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-system-settings depends on indicator-power (>= 12.10.6+15.04.20150130); however:
  Package indicator-power is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-system-settings depends on powerd (>= 0.15) | gnome-settings-daemon; however:
  Package powerd is not configured yet.
  Package gnome-settings-daemon is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-system-settings (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager-gnome:
 network-manager-gnome depends on network-manager (>= 1.1); however:
  Package network-manager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cryptsetup:
 cryptsetup depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.91) | linux-initramfs-tool; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
  Package linux-initramfs-tool is not installed.
  Package initramfs-tools which provides linux-initramfs-tool is not configured yet.
 cryptsetup depends on plymouth; however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cryptsetup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs-backends:
 gvfs-backends depends on gvfs (= 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.1); however:
  Package gvfs:amd64 is not configured yet.
 gvfs-backends depends on gvfs-daemons (= 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.1); however:
  Package gvfs-daemons is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs-backends (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of deja-dup-backend-gvfs:
 deja-dup-backend-gvfs depends on gvfs-backends; however:
  Package gvfs-backends is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package deja-dup-backend-gvfs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs-fuse:
 gvfs-fuse depends on gvfs (= 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.1); however:
  Package gvfs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs-fuse (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic:
 linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic depends on initramfs-tools | linux-initramfs-tool; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
  Package linux-initramfs-tool is not installed.
  Package initramfs-tools which provides linux-initramfs-tool is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.28.30); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-lts-wily:
 linux-generic-lts-wily depends on linux-generic; however:
  Package linux-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-lts-wily (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 initramfs-tools-core
 initramfs-tools
 brltty
 bluez
 plymouth
 mountall
 upstart
 apparmor
 lightdm
 mysql-server-5.7
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 console-setup
 kbd
 console-setup-linux
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
 apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu
 media-player-info
 rhythmbox
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
 rhythmbox-plugins
 udisks2
 gvfs-daemons
 gvfs:amd64
 nautilus
 brasero
 python3-apparmor-click
 click-apparmor
 network-manager
 indicator-network
 upower
 indicator-power
 powerd
 pulseaudio
 indicator-sound
 gnome-bluetooth
 indicator-bluetooth
 unity-control-center
 ubuntu-system-settings
 network-manager-gnome
 cryptsetup
 gvfs-backends
 deja-dup-backend-gvfs
 gvfs-fuse
 linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-generic-lts-wily
 mysql-server
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tries the following commands as well, but I get the same 'udev' error.

```
   14  sudo apt-get clean
   15  sudo apt-get autoremove
   16  sudo apt-get update
   17  sudo apt-get upgrade
   18  sudo dpkg --configure -a
   19  sudo apt-get install -f
   20  sudo apt-get --purge remove udev
   21  sudo apt-get update
   22  sudo apt-get clean
   23  sudo apt-get autoremove
   24  sudo apt-get autoremove -f
   25  sudo apt-get update
   26  sudo apt-get upgrade
   27  sudo apt-get upgrade -f
   28  sudo apt-get download udev
   30  sudo dpkg -i --force-confmiss udev_229-4ubuntu6_amd64.deb
   31  sudo apt-get install udev
   33  sudo apt-get install -f
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have an error in udev post-installation script `subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1` , so just make installation skip that script using `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.postinst.backup` then `sudo apt-get install -f` to cont. previous installation. It sould be fine, just non robust scripts that don't expect some rare situations. copy back that script after you finish.

Comment: @Sneetsher that seems to work, currently doing its' thing. Could you add your comment as an answer so I can mark it if it does the job ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have an error in udev post-installation script

> ```
> addgroup: The group `input' already exists and is not a system group. Exiting.
> dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
> subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
> ```

The other packages are just waiting for udev to complete

> ```
>  initramfs-tools-core depends on udev; however:
>   Package udev is not configured yet.
> ...
>  initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-core (= 0.122ubuntu8.1); however:
>   Package initramfs-tools-core is not configured yet.
> ```

1. So just make installation skip that script using

   ```
   sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.postinst.backup
   ```
2. then command below to continue previous installation.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```

It should be fine, just non robust scripts that don't expect some rare situations. Copy back that script after you finish.

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.postinst.backup /var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.postinst
```

Comment: You sir are my hero!

Comment: i had similar problem after upgrading to 20.04 from 18.04 & this worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

**So do not panic at all, take a deep breath**

first make a backup of udev.postinst

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/udev.postinst.backup
```

then just install udev

```
sudo  apt-get install udev
```

after that

```
sudo  dpkg --configure -a
```

now

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

**all done , now relax and drink a cup of coffee**

Answer (score -2):

apt-get --purge remove udev

y

Enter

1

apt-get upgrade

apt autoremove

Den it should be as fine as hell

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Removing `udev` will remove many important dependent packages. Most probably breaks desktop environment and some device drivers may not loaded correctly.